# different forms displayed in/out IDE for ASCII control characters

Tags: c, ascii

The following program is used to print the characters with ASCII from 1 to 126.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=1;
    char c=1;
    for(c=1; c<=126; c++)
    {
        printf("%c ",c);
        i++;
        if(i%10==0)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When running the program in the IDE (vs6.0 or codeblocks). It looks like this
"[result when running in the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXrjW.jpg)"

But when I run it in an independent cmd terminal out the IDE. it displays differently. See "[result when running out the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy3Lp.jpg)"

Comment: It looks like code blocks is setting a default character-set (e.g. UTF-8) while the default for your system is different. It could also be a LOCALE issue (more likely the charset).

Comment: Thank you very much. I also think it is a charset issue. I don't know how ti fix it. The program works well in another computer.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The basic question is *"Why does the code above print differently when run inside codeblocks and when run directly from a terminal?"* the way I interpret it. It is probably a better question for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/), [**Server Fault**](http://serverfault.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In ASCII, the characters 0 to 31 are non-printable characters. Other symbol tables might specify a symbol for those indexes.